# Spring boot : A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have converted a classic spring framework application to Spring Boot, and now I getting this:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-04-07 08:32:47.588  INFO 2448 --- [           main] b.c.j.besser.core.BesserCoreApplication  : Starting BesserCoreApplication on roberton with PID 2448 (D:\JJW\srcBesser\besser-core\target\classes started by Roberto in D:\JJW\srcBesser\besser-core)
2016-04-07 08:32:47.599  INFO 2448 --- [           main] b.c.j.besser.core.BesserCoreApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-04-07 08:32:48.059  INFO 2448 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@47d9a273: startup date [Thu Apr 07 08:32:48 BRT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-07 08:32:51.815  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.s.s.a.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : No TaskExecutor bean found for async annotation processing.
2016-04-07 08:32:52.114  INFO 2448 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c59662e5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-07 08:32:52.506  INFO 2448 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-07 08:32:52.517  INFO 2448 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@2bbb44da' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-07 08:32:52.543  INFO 2448 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78749757] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-07 08:32:52.604  INFO 2448 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-07 08:32:52.644  INFO 2448 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c7519eb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-07 08:32:52.760  INFO 2448 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d2e449] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-04-07 08:32:54.537  INFO 2448 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-04-07 08:32:54.564  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-04-07 08:32:54.566  INFO 2448 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
2016-04-07 08:32:55.770  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2016-04-07 08:32:55.778  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-04-07 08:32:55.779  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7727 ms
2016-04-07 08:32:57.002  INFO 2448 --- [g-Init-Reporter] com.mchange.v2.log.MLog                  : MLog clients using slf4j logging.
2016-04-07 08:32:57.093  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry         : Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.1 [built 16-June-2015 00:06:36 -0700; debug? true; trace: 10]
2016-04-07 08:32:57.926  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'pu'
2016-04-07 08:32:57.957  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: pu
    ...]
2016-04-07 08:32:58.158  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-04-07 08:32:58.163  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-04-07 08:32:58.167  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-04-07 08:32:58.750  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-04-07 08:32:59.079  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.m.v.c.i.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource   : Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 30000, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1b61c019f1uq94rx1amrowc|b5a3aa3, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1b61c019f1uq94rx1amrowc|b5a3aa3, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 300, initialPoolSize -> 2, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.15.250:/datasource/patomuxi/mercotoys.fdb?encoding=ISO8859_1, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 900, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> select first 1 1 from RDB$DATABASE, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2016-04-07 08:32:59.115  WARN 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : Bad pool size config, start 2 < min 3. Using 3 as start.
2016-04-07 08:32:59.854  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect
2016-04-07 08:33:00.992  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-04-07 08:33:16.722  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-07 08:33:16.725  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] .e.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-04-07 08:33:16.725  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'tokenAuthenticationFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-07 08:33:16.725  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-04-07 08:33:17.409  INFO 2448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4fd33ae3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7835caf0, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4ea80253, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5d0beb29, br.com.jjw.besser.core.authentication.TokenAuthenticationFilter@63293d93, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@737d8efb, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1b678950, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@43f05caf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2afe0b48, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@82e98a2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2c14c825, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3c2b82e3]
2016-04-07 08:33:25.841  WARN 2448 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [br/com/jjw/besser/core/configuration/MvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
2016-04-07 08:33:25.869  INFO 2448 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'pu'
2016-04-07 08:33:25.879  INFO 2448 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-04-07 08:33:25.897 ERROR 2448 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [br/com/jjw/besser/core/configuration/MvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at br.com.jjw.besser.core.BesserCoreApplication.main(BesserCoreApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:451) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.jjw.besser.core.configuration.MvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb14c397.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$23(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.jjw.besser.core.configuration.MvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb14c397$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1f6cf842.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.jjw.besser.core.configuration.MvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb14c397.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

This is the root of the cause, the **messageSource** bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messages = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messages.setBasenames("classpath:beanValidation", "classpath:errors");
        messages.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messages;
    }

    @Override
    protected Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }
}
```

When I rename the **messageSource** method to **messageSource2** it works, but I'm not abble to use my **LocalizedMessageService** that autowire the default **MessageSource** to query for my custom messages.

How can I add custom message base names to the default MessageSource?

Comment: have you added any servlet mapping or @Servlet,@Configuration annotation?
also have a look at `br.com.jjw.besser.core.BesserCoreApplication.main(BesserCoreApplication.java:15) `

Comment: You might also want to have a look at this https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/.. because you haven't shared your code it's difficult to assess what you are missing.

Comment: In order to get some help please share at least your configuration files that bootstrap your application

Comment: Add your `MvcConfiguration` class. I'm guessing that you're trying to use `configureDefaultServletHandling` method.

Comment: I have felt this pain before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832792/a-servletcontext-is-required-to-configure-default-servlet-handling-error-when Good Luck

Comment: I found the issue, please read the question again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved.

I have separated the **messageSource** bean from the **MvcConfiguration**, I put it inside another configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class LocalizationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messages = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messages.setBasenames("classpath:beanValidation", "classpath:errors");
        messages.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messages;
    }

}
```

Aparently, my WebMvcConfigurationSupport extension cannot instantiate the messageSource.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing a solution. How do you use it in your `getValidator()` method now? You have a field of type `LocalizationConfiguration` in your `MvcConfiguration` class?

Comment: I haven't defined an Validator, I'm using the Spring Boot auto configurator for instantiate the validador. You just need to have `hibernate-validator` in your class path and the spring takes care about using the `messageSource` bean as the source of your localization.